# Steam crashes in Play on Linux after update

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

I just opened up Play on Linux and tried to launch Windows Steam. It installed an update and then crashed.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Steam but had the same issue when I tried to launch steam.

Has anyone else had this issue? What information do you need to know? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Steam was working fine until today.

Here's the data from the debug screen: https://pastebin.com/3iVBfbNW

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and the problem is solved. You should update your wine in playonlinux like this. I mean you should choose "wine 2.12-fix43315".

[image: wine 2.12-fix43315]